# How to diplay system tray icon using Mono (Linux)?

Tags: c#, qt, mono, gtk#, system-tray

I am using GTK# 2.12 as it is described [here](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/widgets/notification-icon/).

But when I use a PNG image with transparency, KDE does not want to redraw the transparent parts of the image. So, I see the old bitmap (not panel bar) on transparent parts of image.

I guess that it can be bug inside GTK# itself. So, I am looking for a new way to display system tray icons using mono. Maybe some library over QSystemTrayIcon could do it. Ideally, it should be cross-platform. So, on Windows, it should also be displayed.

Alternatively, I can try to implement platform invoke for Linux version (maybe best option). But please give me some example... I am new for Qt and platform invocation in Linux.

Comment: Why don't you just use `tray = new QSystemTrayIcon(this); tray->setIcon(QIcon(":/gui/logo.png")); /* ... */; tray->show();`?

Comment: Do you know what Mono, GTK# means? I need code allowing to use C# to build this application, not C++.

Comment: Yes, I was using mono some 8 years ago, but why would you need mono? I am not saying you do not, but I am asking for justification.

Comment: Yes, it is .Net application.

Comment: Have you tried qyoto, qtsharp or qt4dotnet? I think it is a mono question rather than Qt then.

Comment: QTSharp docs: For now, Qt MinGW for Windows has been the only tested version. Qt for OS X and Linux are planned, Qt for VC++ has not been planned for now.

Comment: Qyoto: I have downloaded it in source, but as I said in my question I am new for Linux development, so it will be good to get some example. I will check qt4dotnet.

Comment: Gtk 2.12 came out a decade ago -- it's surprising that it still works with modern desktops at all.  Have you considered porting to Gtk 3?  It's possible that this bug was solved long ago.

Comment: MrEricSir, I guess it is good idea. It is still in beta so I was a bit worrying and downloaded last stable.

Comment: I spent a lot of time to compile GTK#3 for CentOS 6.6. And unfortunately bug is still present! It looks better, not tooltip bugs, it has correct styles, but there is still problem with icon.

Comment: Finally I used another icon and bug disappeared... But thanks for GTK3# recommendation... It is really much more stable even if it is beta.

Comment: @Maxim: so what do you want me to put in the answer then?

Comment: If we can think that it is answer about Qyoto then I think we need url to repository with "qyoto-qtcore-native" (please read comment under your answer). In addition it will be good to understand how to create tray icon using native calls to for example QSystemTrayIcon (like it is possible to use DllImport for WinApi).

Answer (score 1):

I think you ought to try updating your gtk version since the version that you are trying to use is very old. It is like using Qt 3 or so. They were OK some ten years ago. It is quite possible that the bug was fixed a long while ago for such a basic functionality.

If you want to stick with ancient software, here is a Qt wrapper solution though just for the challenge of it.

`QYoto` from KDE is not that much maintained anymore, but it is probably still the best choice out of the wrappers, so here goes the example code for this:

```
using Qyoto;

class Program { 
    public static void Main(string[] args) { 
        new QApplication(args); 
        var tray = new QSystemTrayIcon(this);
        tray.SetIcon(new QIcon(":/gui/logo.png"));
        ...
        tray.Show();
        QApplication.Exec(); 
  }   
}
```

Comment: Where can I get QSystemTrayIcon for Mono?

Comment: Where can I download it? I understand how to use QSystemTrayIcon. I do not know how to get assemblies with it.

Comment: @Maxim: e.g. https://bitbucket.org/dzmuh/qyoto.examples/src/1aebe51206d555dc2f27456509b688917ef74f3f/Lib/ but to be honest, you should not use Qyoto as it is unmaintained. I only wrote it up for the challenge that it can be done. You should find some gtk# or native mono way.

Comment: SetIcon is absent in library downloaded using provided bitbucket URL. It has only property Icon. So it is OK... but finally executed application cannot find dll "qyoto-qtcore-native", it is absent in that repository. QtCore.SmokeInvocation ---> System.DllNotFoundException: qyoto-qtcore-native

Comment: @Maxim: please highlight my nickname when writing to me. I have just noticed this... Please try downloading it from here: http://download.kde.org/stable/4.14.3/src/qyoto-4.14.3.tar.xz